# How to implement pagination in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have developed a form in word press using page.php. And now i am displaying all my form data fetching from data base. But when i am displaying all my records my page goes to much scroll. Now i want to implement pagination on my page. Any one can suggest me please how i can implement pagination in word press. As i am implementing pagination first time so i use this tutorial find from some where.. its work fine but does not create proper link for next page records. Thanks...

```
if ( !( isset( $pagenum ) ) ) {
     $pagenum = 1;
}
```

> > Here we count the number of results
> >     Edit $data to be your query

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM red_donation_info") or die( mysql_error() );
$rows = mysql_num_rows( $data );
```

> > This is the number of results displayed per page

```
 $page_rows = 10;
```

> > This tells us the page number of our last page

```
$last = ceil( $rows / $page_rows );
```

> > this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages

```
if ( $pagenum < 1 ) {
     $pagenum = 1;
 } elseif ( $pagenum > $last ) {
     $pagenum = $last;
 }
```

> > This sets the range to display in our query

```
$max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
```

> > This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it

```
$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM red_donation_info $max") or die(mysql_error());
```

> > This is where you display your query results

```
while ( $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p ) ) {
      print $info['Name'];
      echo "<br>";
 }
 echo "<p>";
```

> > This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages

```
 echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";
```

> > First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

```
if ( $pagenum == 1 ) {
 } else {
    echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
    echo " ";
    $previous = $pagenum-1;
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";
 }
```

> > just a spacer

```
echo " ---- ";
```

> > This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

```
if ( $pagenum == $last ) {
 } else {
     $next = $pagenum + 1;
     echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";
     echo " ";
     echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid mysql_* functions

```
$_GET['start'] = isset($_GET['start']) && ctype_digit($_GET['start']) ? abs(@intval($_GET['start'])) : 0;
$select = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `red_donation_info`");
$total  = mysql_result($select, 0, 0);
$pages  = ceil($total / 10);
$ret    = '';
for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    $start = ($i - 1) * 10;
    $ret  .= "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?start=".$start."'>Page ".$i."</a>, ";
}
echo "Page: ".substr($ret, 0, -2);
$mainSelect = mysql_query("SELECT `whatever` FROM `red_donation_info` LIMIT ".$_GET['start'].", 10");
// Loop through data here
```

That's something along the lines of what I'd do..
Not tested, so may need edits